# How do u increment one field every time and the other only if it's greater than a certain number with multi true ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The following code decrements `class_number` just fine, but not `number_of_classes` because of the `$gt` operator.

```
posts.update({ 'title':doc.title, 'author':doc.author, 'class_number':{ '$gt': doc.class_number } }, 
             { '$inc': { 'number_of_classes':-1 , 'class_number':-1} }, 
             { multi: true }, function(err, dox){....
```

I need to decrement `number_of_classes` once every time, but only each `class_number` above a certain value.  Is there a way to do this in one statment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to "conditionally" update one field and not another, just as there is no way to "reference" an existing value of a field in a document during an update statement. Much as your current statement provides, you can only perform the "conditions" on the **query** that you pass to the update.

So if you are trying to hit a "floor" of 0 then your "safe" method is in two operations:

```
db.collection.update(
     { "title":doc.title, "author":doc.author },
     { "$inc": "number_of_classes": -1 }
)

db.collection.update(
     { 
         "title":doc.title, 
         "author":doc.author,
         "$and": [
             { "class_number": { "$gt": 0 } },
             { "class_number": { "$gt": doc.class_number } }
         ]
     },
     { "$inc": "class_number": -1 }
)
```

Or however that logic works for you in actual updates.

In future versions ( as of writing ) you can ["batch"](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/update/#bulk-update) these updates into a single request, but they actually are still two operations, even though sent to the server only once.

I do somehow suspect that due to the way you are writing this statement that you are actually trying to solve some kind of "allocation" problem. And that would be a different question to the way you are asking this here.